# .animate() position overrides manual .offset() assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a bunch of constantly scrolling objects on the screen, each assigned a number. When you press one of their numbers, it will go far left off the screen so it can scroll back on. When I try to reassign the position of the element using offset, it only disappears for a sec then continues scrolling where it was before. I think it's because animate() is still going on while I try to change it, so it changes for a second then animate takes it back to where it was. How do I override animate when it is in an entirely different function?

Here's where I try to manually assign:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which == 48){
            $('#foo').offset({top:8, left:-600});
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the animation function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#foo').animate({
            left : "+=10"
        },{ duration: 200, queue: false });
    },200);
}
```

Comment: instaed of doing +=10, assign a global variable to hold its value, and have both functions use that.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean. If I assign a global variable, won't it just assign the same position over and over again and not move anywhere when I animate it?

Comment: No because youll be updating the global variable as you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animate is going off what it used last. If you set a global variable like Rooster mentioned you should be able to use that. Try something like this. If this doesnt work make a Fiddle and then I can play with it directly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var leftPos = $('#foo').postion().left;
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if(e.which == 48){
            leftPos = -600;
            $('#foo').offset({top:8, left:leftPos});
        }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        leftPos +=10;
        $('#foo').animate({
            left : leftPos
        },{ duration: 200, queue: false });
    },200);
});
```